# Keyboard is not showing adding TTNavigator as a subview

Tags: ios, three20

I'm trying to create an slide backmenu, like on facebook or path, but using the three20 framework. The thing is that I've found a solution to do the the trick and I'm using this way :

```
    SMMenu * tabBar = [[SMMenu alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview: tabBar.view];
    [self.window addSubview: navigator.window];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I've created a rear view with a TableController called SMMenu, then a front view that is a TTNavigator called navigator. Then I add both subviews to an object window, that I make Key.

Until here is all ok, is working nice.

The thing is that right now, I found that the keyboard is not showing. That's pretty weird, please I need help!

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm sorry if I don't give time to answer my questions, but I found a possible solution to my problem, and I will left here for future reference, or for anyone in the same situation.

I don't know If what I've done is crazy but, I thought that ttnavigator is not showing the keyboard view because it was not key window. So I've tried to add as a key and it works ... here it is the example of what I've done :

```
SMMenu * rearMenu = [[SMMenu alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:rearMenu.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[self addShadow: navigator.window]; //this is a styling element
[navigator.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I really don't know what I'm doing :) ... but is working fine.